How to handle events representing cross-domain knowledge
I've been looking at DDD lately as part of playing with Spring Modulith, and I'm getting hung up a bit on how to approach events which cross between contexts.
To provide a concrete example based on a (currently monolithic) domain I work with day to day, let's say we have three parts to a system... three bounded contexts, if I'm using the term correctly.

"Accounting" basically consists of financial Accounts, and a sequence of debit and credit Transactions over time... the objective being to keep track of how much a customer owes. This system is very simple — it doesn't know anything about what those transactions actually represent — so it should be very loosely coupled with anything it interacts with.
"Billing" takes in data from various sources, and periodically generates an Invoice for a customer — i.e. an itemised record of what they should be paying for the services they've been consuming. Without getting into the complexities, the relevant detail is that when an invoice is created here, a Transaction should also be created in Accounting.
"Payments" is the counterpart of billing... a customer will periodically pay what they owe, by some unspecified means (cash, direct debit, crypto, whatever). And again, when a Payment is created here, a Transaction should be created in Accounting.

So here's the bit that's bugging me. "Billing" and "Payments" both need to notify "Accounting", so that it can create transactions for the new invoices and payments... so logically, it seems that they should emit "InvoiceCreated" and "PaymentCreated" events for others to pick up.
Except that "Accounting" has no idea what an Invoice or a Payment are. It only knows about Transactions, and it doesn't want to know any more than that (because this is a simplified example; in reality there are other systems which may (or may not) be in play).
However, doing things the other way around — having Billing and Payments emit "PleaseCreateATransaction" events — doesn't seem right either. From a pragmatic point of view, it's much more acceptable to me for Billing and Payments to have that kind of knowledge of Accounting than vice-versa, but it feels inelegant at a design level.
So to come to the actual question — what's the best practices for this kind of thing? It must be a common consideration — any communication between contexts requires some awareness of what each other do — but it's not clear how best to manage it.

I think your accounting component should not be so simple, and it should actually know what invoices and payments are. An alternative would be for those other systems to emit "transaction" events, which moves the responsibility of understanding "transactions" to two other systems. Doesn't seem to be worth it.

Bounded Contexts are language boundaries. When domain experts use the same term that has a different meaning in their context, you stumbled upon such a boundary. That doesn't seem to be the case here, this could well be the Financial Bounded Context that knows all these concepts. Either way, the DDD pattern to guard Bounded Contexts from terminology pollution from other contexts is the Anti-corruption Layer pattern (ACL).

@RikD In a small business, the accountant may be in charge of the billing and the payments.  However,  both billing and payments can be extremely complex in medium and large companies, as it involves many operational details, like unit price, price conditions, rebates, payment mechanisms, etc... that have their  very specific language with very specific terms that are not part of traditional accounting.

"but it feels inelegant at a design level" Can you elaborate on this? What problem do you see with creating a transaction (maybe credits and debits) along with a reference to the associated invoice or payment.

@Christophe Exactly so. As I said, this is a simplified learning exercise based on a domain I'm familiar with — but these are definitely different systems. "Accounting" is pure book-keeping... in reality, it would be quite closely linked to the company financial system. "Billing" is hugely complex but focused on figuring out how much to charge the customer for the services they're using... and yes, lots of stuff around pricing, rebates, processing usage measurements, contracts, etc.

@JimmyJames Maybe that's where I'm going wrong in worrying about that, but the concern was two-fold. One is that "PleaseCreateATransaction" doesn't sound like an event associated with the Billing or Payment systems... it's more of an instruction (but maybe that's okay if we call it a "command" instead of "event"?).
The second is that it implies a strong degree of cross-domain knowledge (Billing and Payments need to know what a Transaction is)... and pragmatically, I'm okay with that, but this being a learning exercise, I'm trying to understand the idealist perspective on the matter.

Oh, and for perspective, I work on an monolith of some millions of lines of code that's been growing and evolving for decades...
So at least in part, this question is me thinking about how to put some dividing lines through what's currently an exceedingly-complex "omni-domain".

There are going to be some inherent dependencies between your domains because they are part of the requirements.  I kind of got the sense that you are wrangling with an existing solution and how to untangle it (I've been there.) You might want to step away from the technical details and whiteboard things out.  Maybe work with a business SME. Once you have things described in the abstract, then come back to the software.

@JimmyJames Sort of, though as I said, this is more of a learning exercise expressed through a real business domain, rather than an immediate work-related problem I'm trying to solve right now... trying to understand how others, particularly DDD proponents, would approach problems of this nature. It's why I keep distinguishing between what I'm willing to do as a pragmatist, and what the idealist answer might be.

Typically, accounts payables and account receivables are sub-ledgers in the accounting context.  They register accounting transactions with vendors and customers.
Accounting transactions with vendors and customers are derived from payable invoices and customer billing. They do not need to know all the details, but only those relevant to the debts/liabilities (accounting terms), the taxes (also accounting) and the split of the total amounts by expense/income account.
The first idea is then to let accounting subscribe to invoice payables events and billing events. The consistency between billing/payables and accounting could be managed via the saga.  Unfortunately, this approach requires accounting to know about payables and billing events, which creates an undesired coupling for such a general functionality as accounting.  This is not in the spirit of sound separation of concerns.
To avoid accounting being polluted by billing/payables context,  an anti-corruption layer should be introduced. In the case of domain events,  this layer transforms incoming events from another context into commands of the current context.  In other words,  the accounting ledger would subscribe to the billing via an abstract ACL layer.  This layer would receive the billing events, and translate them into an accounting command (or an accounting event, depending on how many indirections you are ready to deal with) that uses only accouting terms. You could imagine for example a pseudo event BusinessEventRegidteted and act upon it.
The accounting context would therewith stay solely focused on accounting context.  All knowledge of the billing context would be isolated in the ACL.  If the billing context would change,  only ACL would need to be adapted to new mapping.
The bounded context in your case are interdependent.  Because billing may want to keep track of the accounting documents registered for the transaction, as evidence.  It may also want to be kept up-to date, when the customer's money was received for launching subsequent process steps/tasks.  So very probably, you'll have also an ACL to isolate billing from accounting concepts.
A slightly different approach could be keep accounting domain without ACL but foresee some generic events that causes postings in its different subledgers.  A process orchestration object could be part of the billing ACL  and translate the relevant billing events (e.g. BillCreated) into an accounting event (e.g. ReceivableTransactionCreated or BusinessTransactionCeated).

Ah, that makes sense. There's a quote from one of the those links that describes an ACL as "translating an event into a command.", which is a perfect description of my problem with how to model the event/command. So if I was following a purist approach, I essentially have a layer between the two domains providing that translation.

You're correct that the contexts are somewhat interdependent, but I'm trying to keep that one-way as much as possible. It's okay for other elements to know about Accounting, because many contexts will understand the concept of an Account as a common identity that gets propagated around, and some will need to understand debts and due dates and the like.
But I'm much less comfortable with Accounting having too much awareness of the ecosystem around it, because that's a basic building block that should be quite narrow in focus.

@SimonGeard I share a similar understanding about what the dependencies should be. I'd personally go for the approach proposed in the last paragraph, which combines the principle of event subscriptions yet keep the accounting domain clean and let the ACL on the accounting consumer side.

Disclaimer
For the purpose of the explanation, it's irrelevant whether we consider these bounded contexts as part of the same monolithic runtime or if they're completely separate microservices, their interaction should be modeled/designed with the same considerations in mind.
I noticed I slipped into the microservice force of habit when referring to HTTP endpoints, but everything discussed in this answer has an equivalent way to achieve in in the same runtime. Instead of an HTTP endpoint, you can just as well think of an Accounting service that is intended to be called by other contexts.
This answer focuses on the design principles more so than the syntax required to implement it.

Abstractions as a protection

Except that "Accounting" has no idea what an Invoice or a Payment are.

This is why a codebase should have abstraction/mapping layers inbetween its domain layer (which has no outside dependencies) and the real world. At some point your application needs to talk to the outside world and needs to be aware of who the outside world is and how to talk to them.
Using a simpler example: your service might be using a SQL database to persist its data. Some part of your codebase will have to couple itself to the fact that it's using SQL (or a SQL-oriented ORM).
The important part is that the domain part of your codebase is not the right place to put that knowledge. It has to be somewhere, but definitely not there.
I refer to these kinds of boundaries to the outside world as "welcome mats", where you're allowed to walk with dirty shoes (= tight coupling to outside sources), but you're supposed to clean/take off those shoes before you walk into the house (domain).
Welcome mats do the dirty work

Except that "Accounting" has no idea what an Invoice or a Payment are.

The same is true in your scenario. The part of your Accounting codebase that integrates with the real world is part of the welcome mat, and there is no issue with that welcome mat containing the obviously necessary information to be able to communicate with the outside world.

It only knows about Transactions, and it doesn't want to know any more than that

Past the welcome mat, when the dirty shoes are off, you should indeed only talk about transactions. But that doesn't apply to what happens on the welcome mat.
On the welcome mat, you can receive the "InvoiceCreated" and "PaymentCreated" events and map them to the appropriate Transaction. After mapping, you can pass that "clean" transaction into the domain services, which indeed only speak the language of transactions.
Specifically for the purpose of a monolithic runtime, I would be separating the dirty welcome mat (which I'd refer to as an Adapter) from the clean domain service (which I'd refer to as a Service if no better name presents itself).

However, doing things the other way around — having Billing and Payments emit "PleaseCreateATransaction" events — doesn't seem right either.

The short answer here is that an event is described from the perspective of the source, not a specific consumer you have in mind; so yes "PleaseCreateATransaction" is a bad design.
Examining a different approach
However, there is a third option you glossed over, and I want to point it out for the sake of applying the same advice to it:

Accounting has an HTTP endpoint which Billing and Payments call

When we were talking about the event model, Billing and Payments were the source/owner/designer of their event; and Accounting was its consumer. Now, with an HTTP endpoint, the roles of source/owner/designer and consumer are reversed.
Since Accounting owns and designs this endpoint, it will only talk about transactions. For the purpose of the example, it'd be a "CreateTransaction" endpoint.
Now, since Billing/Payments are the consumer, it is their welcome mat that we have to consider. For all intents and purposes, the principle is the same whether Billing is persising its own data in its data store, or if it's talking to Accounting to create a transaction, in the sense that:

The domain logic works with a Bill domain model.
The Billing welcome mat takes this model, maps it to a "dirty" model that relies on outside knowledge (whether this is a SQL INSERT command or a Transaction API model to be sent to the Accounting endpoint)
The Billing welcome mat sends the dirty model to the outside world.


Conclusion
Effectively, across this whole answer, the universal truth is that the consumer needs a welcome mat in order to process a "dirty" consumed model and map it from/to a clean domain model that its domain services are willing to work with.
That is the core of the answer: you need an abstraction layer that does the dirty work, so that your domain layer can do the clean work.

Different terminology, but I guess "welcome mat" is basically the same thing that Christophe refers to as "anti-corruption layer"... a place between domains which is allowed to have a bigger-picture than the domains, but sitting outside of those domains where it can't contaminate them with forbidden knowledge?
I do appreciate the note about HTTP. Yes, my question asks about events, but it's also applicable to direct synchronous comms... the only difference is which door the mat sits outside of.

@SimonGeard: Events themselves can also be synchronous comms when implemented within a monolith's runtime. Events focus on a pubsub model but they don't tie themselves to being inherently (a)sync.

True, events don't have to be async (and indeed, I don't think they are by default in the framework I'm using), but they express what I think of as an asynchronous mindset.

@SimonGeard: This is  tangential to the main question but I would advise caution on conflating (a)synchronicity and the distinction between command/event-driven designs. Their overlap is minimal and it makes you liable to exclude other possible solutions on the assumption that A inevitably ties itself to B1 and thus end up ignoring B2 as a possible avenue.

When crossing domain boundaries you can implement a Domain Service to perform the work. ie
OrderService
   PlaceOrder(Order o)
   {
       Billing.CreateBill(order.ItemName, order.amount);
       Payments.TakePayment(order.Cardnumber, order.amount);
       Accounts.CreateTransaction(order.CustomerId,order.amount);
   }

